# How to pass HTML form POST params to PHP using AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, http-post

I am trying to implement file upload functionality on my site.

I have created the actual PHP script for uploading and this is what I've added to my HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="PHPScripts/upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="file" id="browseButton" name="image" onchange="this.form.submit();" />
</form>
```

This triggers the upload.php as expected, however, this is not what I want to achieve exactly. I want to implement AJAX instead. So, when the user chooses the file, I want to trigger the JavaScript function and I want that function to call the upload.php subsequently.

But there's a problem: How am I supposed to pass the POST parameters (i.e. `$_POST["upload"]` and `$_FILES["image"]`) to PHP function through the JavaScript? I know it's supposed to be simple, but I'm stuck. Thanks for clarifying.

#### Update

Changelog explained that this is not possible in the way I imagined. My ultimate goal is to achieve the following:

1. User browses for an image to upload.
2. PHP uploads the image to the designated location on the server machine.
3. (This is critical) The uploaded file is presented in a predefined  tag after it has been successfully uploaded. Could you give some recommendations on how to achieve the third step? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do the file upload via AJAX.

Basically what an AJAX interception does is it serializes the values on your form (you can try `$('#form_id').serialize()` on your console to see what it does).

Because the file is read from the disk, you don't have that data available at submit time and can't do it via AJAX like you can with regular fields.

Comment: OK, got it. My ultimate goal is to achieve the following: 1. User browses for an image to upload. 2. PHP uploads the image to the designated location on the server machine. 3. (This is critical) The uploaded file is presented in a predefined `<img>` tag after it has been successfully uploaded. Could you give some recommendations on how to achieve the third step? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer was probably accurate at the time, things have changed a bit since early 2011.  Even now, though, there are commenters on Stackoverflow who continue to insist that you cannot upload files via ajax.  **This is simply not true.**

## Upload Files Via Ajax w/ Parameters: Option 1

The [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), combined with [XMLHttpRequest level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) allow you to send files via "ajax".  You can do so using the [`FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), which allows you to include parameters along with your file(s) in the request payload.  Sending a `FormData` object via XHR will result in a multipart encoded request.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file1', file1);
formData.append('file2', file2);
formData.append('param1', 'foo');
formData.append('param2', 'bar');

xhr.open('POST', '/my/endpoint', true);

xhr.send(formData);
```

The obvious benefits of using `FormData` is the ability to send multiple files in the same request and associate parameters in the request payload.  If you are sending a POST or PUT request, your parameters should probably be in the payload anyway.  One small annoyance involves the Content-Length header value.

## Uploading Files Via Ajax w/ Parameters: Option 2

Another, simpler option is to simply send a request that includes the entire file as the request body:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', '/my/endpoint?param1=foo&param2=bar', true);

xhr.send(file1);
```

With this approach, any parameters must be sent as part of a URI's query string.  This *may* be a bit confusing server-side, as it generally is expected that parameters for POST requests are sent in the request body.  Note that you also must send a separate request for each file, which may or may not be important, depending on your workflow.

## Browser Support For Uploading Files Via Ajax

Currently all browsers, other than IE9 and older, along with Android 2.3.x and, of course, iOS5 have sufficient support for the File API to make this all possible.

For browsers that do not support the File API, you will have to make use of a `<form>` to upload files.  You can create a hidden iframe (or iframes) with a `<form>` as the body containing `<input>` elements that represent your file(s) and parameter(s) and submit that form via javascript to give an "ajaxy" look and feel to your application, even without File API support.